# How to get dynamically created textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get dynamically created textbox value in asp.net

This is code which I have created in this code text box are created but when I will input the value in the text and retrieve the value from dynamically created text box it give error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Below is my code...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Generate initial textboxes 
        GenerateButton_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
protected void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Generate textboxes 
    int z = int.Parse(HowManyToGenerateTextBox.Text);

    Panel1.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        TextBox s = new TextBox();
        s.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
        Session[s.ID] = s;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(s);
    }
}
protected void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Calculate sum 
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("tb" + i.ToString());
        ResultLabel.Text = txt.Text;


        if (ResultLabel.Text != null)
            sum += int.Parse(ResultLabel.Text);
    }

    ResultLabel.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's the error? (Oh, null reference, I see). Something is nothing: you need to find out where that is happening and you'll know what it it. Debug, step through, and see which object is `null`.

Comment: And where's the error occuring?

Comment: it could be that you are using Session.Count as the n value in your for loop. There may be more Session objects than just what you created. If you have a z value of 5 but there are 6 session objects, then when you reach step 6 it will not find a textbox and throw a null reference exception. Try setting a variable instead like `Session["HowManyToGenerateTextBox"] = z;` and then recall that

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
```

session always contains others parameters

compare `Session.Count` with `z` in `GenerateButton_Click` method. I suppose that they are differents

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend Here is answer

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        GenerateButton_Click(sender, e);
}


public TextBox[] s;

protected void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  int z = Convert.ToInt32(HowManyToGenerateTextBox.Text);
  Panel1.Controls.Clear();
  Array.Resize(ref s, z);
  for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
  {
      s[i] = new TextBox();
      s[i].ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
      s[i].Text = "tb" + i.ToString();
      Session[s[i].ID] = s;
      Panel1.Controls.Add(s[i]);
  }
}
protected void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ResultLabel.Text = s[0].Text;      
}
```

Here is also code
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/854773/How-to-get-dynamically-created-textbox-value